# How do I use a controller within a controller?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I am using Kohana 3.2 and I am having problems calling the ouput of a controller in another controller.

What I want...

In some pages I have got a menu, and in others I don't. I want to use make use of the flexability of the HMVC request system. In the controller of a page I want to call another controller which is responsible for the creation of the menu.

What I have a the moment:

file menu.php:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Menu extends Controller 
{
    private $_model = null;

    public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response)
    {       
        parent::__construct($request, $response);
        $this->_model = Model::factory('menu');
    }

    public function action_getMenu()
    {
        $content = array();
        $content['menuItems'] = $this->_model->getMenuItems();

        // Render and output.
        $this->request->response = View::factory('blocks/menu', $content);
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->request->response->render()); echo '</pre>'; die();
    }   
}
```

somepage.php

```
public function action_index()
{
    $this->template->title = 'someTitle';;
    $contentData['pageTitle'] = 'someTitle';
    $contentData['contentData'] = 'someData';

    #include the menu       
    $menuBlock = Request::factory('menu/getMenu')->execute();
    $menuData =  array('menu' => $menuBlock);
    $this->template->menu = View::factory('pages/menu')->set('menu',$menuData);

    $this->template->content = View::factory('pages/somePage', $contentData);

    $view = $this->response->body($this->template);
    $this->response->body($view);
}
```

If I uncomment the following line in menu.php, I see the menu rendered:

```
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->request->response->render()); echo '</pre>'; die();
```

So I guess that part is alright. The problem is in the following line in somepage.php:

```
$menuBlock = Request::factory('menu/getMenu')->execute();
```

This gives me back a response object. Whatever I do, I do not get the output in $this->template->menu.

$this->template->menu = View::factory('pages/menu')->set('menu',$menuData);

What must I do to have $this->template->menu contain the view, so I can use it correctly?

I hope this all makes sense. This is the way I would like to do it, but maybe I am completely on the wrong track.

Comment: I just found out the answer to my problem 

In somePage.php change :

    $menuBlock = Request::factory('menu/getMenu')->execute();
    $menuData =  array('menu' => $menuBlock);
    $this->template->menu = View::factory('pages/menu')->set('menu',$menuData);

To:

    $this->template->menu = Request::factory('menu/getMenuBlock')->execute()->body();

And in menu.php change:

    $this->request->response = View::factory('blocks/menu', $content);
        
To:

    $request = View::factory('blocks/menu', $content);
    $this->response->body($request);

I hope this will help someone else.

Comment: Also it is not recommended to use __construct() method for your code in kohana. You should use before() (same as __construct()) and after() (same as __destruct()) methods. Don't forget to call parent::before() too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
class Controller_Menu extends Controller
{
    public function action_build()
    {
        // Load the menu view. 
        $view = View::factory('navigation/menu');
        // Return view as response-
        $this->response->body($view->render());
    }
}
```

In your controller get the menu as follows:

```
// Make request and get response body.
$menu = Request::factory('menu/build')->execute()->body();
// e.g. assign menu to template sidebar.
$this->template->sidebar = Request:.factory('menu/build')->execute()->body();
```

I would not use the __construct method in your controllers. Use before() instead, this is sufficient for most of the problems (for example auth):

```
public function before()
{
    // Call aprent before, must be done here.
    parent::before();
    // e.g. heck whether user is logged in.
    if ( !Auth::instance()->logged_in() )
    {
        //Redirect if not logged in or something like this.
    }
}
```

Comment: I already found the solution in less than an hour after posting it. I just forgot to put it here. I have used your answer to improve my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem in less than an hour after asking. 
I just forgot to put it here.

In somePage.php change :

```
$menuBlock = Request::factory('menu/getMenu')->execute(); 
$menuData = array('menu' => $menuBlock); 
$this->template->menu = View::factory('pages/menu')->set('menu',$menuData);
```

To:

```
$this->template->menu = Request::factory('menu/getMenuBlock')->execute()->body();
```

And in menu.php change:

```
$this->request->response = View::factory('blocks/menu', $content);
```

To:

```
$request = View::factory('blocks/menu', $content); 
$this->response->body($request);
```

I hope this will help someone else.